# How can I find $ \int \int_R{ \bigtriangledown \times \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}}dA $ ??

Tags: vector-analysis

$$\overrightarrow{F}=-y\hat{i}+x\hat{j}$$
$$C:r=a \cos{t}\hat{i}+a \sin{t}\hat{j}, o \leq t \leq 2 \pi$$
$$R:x^2+y^2 \leq a^2 $$

Green's Theorem:
$$\oint_C{F}dr=\int \int_R{\bigtriangledown \times \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}}dA$$

$$\bigtriangledown \times \overrightarrow{F}=2 \hat{k}$$
But how can I find  $ \int \int_R{ \bigtriangledown \times \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}}dA $ ??

Comment: Can you find $\hat n$? It is the outward normal to the surface you are integrating over.

Comment: @user88595 Could you give me a hint how to find this?

Comment: What is $R$? You have defined it as $x^2 + y^2 \le a^2$. On which plane does it lie? From there you should be able to see what the normal vector is.

Comment: @user88595 $R$ lies on the plane $xy$, right? How can find the normal vector? The normal vector should be  perpendicular  to the plane, shouldn't it? So should it be on the z-axis?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @user88595 Ok...So we have now $ \int \int_R{ \bigtriangledown \times \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}}dA=  \int \int_R{ \bigtriangledown \times \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{k}}dA =\int \int_R{2}dA$..To find this do I have to say that this double integral is the area of the circle which equals to $ \pi r^2$ (r: radius)? Or is there an other way?

Comment: Well you can just say it is the area of the circle to avoid calculations. Having said that you can also do it by calculating it. Here's a post showing how to calculate it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187987/calculus-proof-for-the-area-of-a-circle

Comment: @user88595 Ok! In the link the integrals are of the form $\int \int_R dxdy$..Is this the same as the integral $\int \int_R{ \nabla \times \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}}dA$ ??

Comment: $$\int\int dxdy = \int\int dA$$

Comment: Aha! Ok!! Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Greens Theorm implies : 
$$\oint_C{F}dr=\int \int_R{\nabla \times \overrightarrow{F}\cdot \hat{k} }dA$$
with $\hat{k}$ is pointing the $z$ direction and the R.H.S is just the normal double integral of $\nabla \times \overrightarrow{F}$ over region $R$ which is the area inside the circle centered at the origin and of radius $a$.

Since $\nabla \times \overrightarrow{F}=2 \hat{k}$, we get
$$\oint_C{F}dr=2\int \int_R{ }dA= 2\pi a^2 $$

Comment: So you mean that $\hat{n}=\hat{k}$?? $\hat{n}$ should be perpendicular to the plane which is the $xy$,that's why $\hat{n}$ is on $z$.Is this correct?

Comment: yeap, greens theorm is stokes theorm for plane, so n=k

Comment: A ok! How did you calculate the last double integral? Is this the area of the circle which equals to $ \pi r^2$ (r: radius)? Or is there an other way?