# Why does squaring of the radius of a circle times pi give us the area?

Tags: geometry

*Why does squaring the radius of a circle times pi equal the area?* (I.e., why does the area of circle representable as $\pi r^2$ ?)*What is the relationship between the radius of a circle and the area?*

Comment: what would you prefer?

Comment: Are you familiar with integration?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the following illustration.

[image: CircleArea.svg]
"[CircleArea](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CircleArea.svg#/media/File:CircleArea.svg)" by Jim.belk - Own work. Licensed under Public Domain via [Wikimedia Commons](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

Comment: You could add a little explanation :)

Comment: I'm glad you like it!

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Calculus proof for the area of a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187987/calculus-proof-for-the-area-of-a-circle)

And this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_disk#Onion_proof

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to square some linear measure of the circle to get to an area. The radius and the circumference are in any case related by a constant - $2\pi$ - and it happens that squaring the radius gives the simplest constant to obtain the area.

There is a pretty visual of how the area and radius are related [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/743459/206402).

Answer (score 0):

if you assume that $\pi$ is the ratio of the diameter of the circle to the circumference, then you can divide the circumference, say, into $1000$ points at equal distance. now join each of these segments to the center to make a small pie. arrange the pieces so that they make an almost rectangle of length $\pi \times \text {radius}$ and width the radius of the circle. the area of this rectangle is $\pi$ times the radius squared.