# The volume of a sphere is given by the formula. Find the rate of change of the volume with respect to r

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm doing this question for my maths assignment and I'm finding it quite annoying to find the right answer.

My question is.  The volume of a sphere is given by the formula

$$ 
V= \frac{4 \pi r^3}{3}
$$
find the rate of change of the volume with 
respect to r.?

Comment: SImply compute the derivative of $\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$.

Comment: Related: [Why is the derivative of a circle's area its perimeter (and similarly for spheres)?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625).

Answer (score 1):

You should just find the differential coefficient with respect to $r$

$$ V= \frac{4 \pi r^3}{3} ; \; \frac{dV}{dr}= 4 \pi r^2. $$

It is known that the volume rate equals its area.

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the differential of $v=(4πr^3)/3$ that is $v'=3*(4πr^2)/3$ = $v'=4πr^2$