# Sphere reducing in size in a tax that is proportional to surface area

Tags: calculus, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, volume

> Suppose that we have a sphere of naphthalene that is sublimating in a tax that is proportional to its surface area. Find the radius of the sphere in a time $t$, knowing that, for a sphere, $V = \frac{4}{3} \pi R^3$ (volume) and $S = 4 \pi R^2$ (surface area).

I did the "obvious" thing here: Since the sphere is decreasing in size:
$$\frac{\textrm{d}V}{\textrm{d}t} = -kS$$
And so:
$$V' = - k \times 4 \pi R^2$$
Since $ V = \frac{4}{3} \pi R^3$, then $V' = 4 \pi R^2 R'$ (by the chain rule, and here $f'$ meaning derivative of $f$ with respect to $t$)
And so:
$$4 \pi R^2 R' = -k \times 4 \pi R^2$$
And then i get:
$$R' = -k$$
So
$$R(t) = -kt + c_1 \quad, c_1 \in \mathbb{R}$$
**Is this correct?** For me, a linear decreasing here doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Your analysis is correct. Related: [Why is the derivative of a circle's area its perimeter (and similarly for spheres)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625)