# Is this a valid integral to prove area of circle?

Tags: calculus, integration, nonstandard-analysis

Similar to the original poster of this question [Is this a valid proof for the area of a circle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4405126/is-this-a-valid-proof-for-the-area-of-a-circle), I am a high school AP Calc BC student using the idea of Riemann sums to add an infinite number of isosceles triangles of area 
$\frac{R^{2}\sin(d\theta)}{2}$
 to determine the area of the circle. This technique produces the sum: 
$\lim_{n \to \infty } \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{R^{2}\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})}{2}$
which does evaluate to $\pi R^{2}$. However, I would like to convert the sum to this integral: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{R^{2}\sin(d\theta)}{2}$, and then evaluate this intergal. Using nonstandard analysis, my guess is to simply $\sin(d\theta)$ as another infinitesimal dω, naively keeping the bounds the same and evaluating $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{R^{2}}{2}d\omega$ does yield the wanted answer: $\pi R^{2}$? I fear this is an abuse of logic and/or notation and would like to know how to approach integrals like the one in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good intuition as $n \to \infty$ we can heuristically substitute $\sin (d\theta)$ with $d\theta$.

More rigourosly we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{R^{2}\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})}{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{R^{2}}{2}\frac{\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})}{\frac{2\pi}{n}}\frac{2\pi}{n} $$

and since

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})}{\frac{2\pi}{n}} =1$$

we obtain

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{2\pi}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{R^{2}}{2}\frac{\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})}{\frac{2\pi}{n}} = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{R^{2}}{2} d\omega = \frac{R^{2}}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\omega =\frac{R^{2}}{2}\cdot 2\pi=\pi R^2$$

Refer also to:

- [Perfect understanding of Riemann Sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2972643/505767)